# Abbreviations of Weeknames in German

Tags: datetime2

This is pretty straight-forward.

I have finally managed to abbreviate weeknames in “British”, i.e. `en-GB`. (What I need is `ngerman`)

But, as I'm working on a German document, I need the date format exactly like this: `Mi, 18. November`. Even better would be `Mi, 18. Nov`.

All I have managed is either `Wed, 18. November`, or `Mittwoch, 18. November`.
If relevant, I'm using XeTeX on VerbTeX.

My Code/MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
letterpaper,%
ngerman,%
5pt,%
]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{isodate} 
\usepackage[%
useregional,
showdow,
ngerman,
]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup*[ngerman]{abbr}
\begin{document}
\DTMlangsetup*{showyear=false}
\DTMdate{2020-11-18}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: @leandriis Oh no, that means I have to dive into defining my own abbreviations.

Comment: Sorry for my previous, now deleted comment. I mixed something up. To get the abbreviated week day and month names, you can use `\DTMlangsetup*[german]{abbr}`.

Comment: @leandriis That's very good, question solved! Interesting, because it doesn't work with `ngerman`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `german` (regionless style) instead of `ngerman` in the optional argument of `\DTMlangsetup*` as shown in the following example in order to get the abbreviated week day and month names. Alternatively, the german module for the `datetime2` package, also offers `de-DE`, `de-AT` and `de-CH` for the corresponding regional variants.

```
\documentclass[%
letterpaper,%
ngerman,%
5pt,%
]{article}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[%
useregional,
showdow
]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup*[german]{abbr}
\begin{document}
\DTMlangsetup*{showyear=false}
\DTMdate{2020-11-18}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Background:

From the `datetime2` documentation:

[image]